# Why do I get 'getLong not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor' when creating a table in Oracle via JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to write a Spark DataFrame to an Oracle table via JDBC. I am able to successfully connect and query the database but when I go to create a new table like this:

```
df.write.jdbc('jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service', create_table,
              mode='overwrite',
              properties={'user': 'user', 'password': 'password']})
```

I get the error message `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getLong not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor`

I suspect this has something to do with column ROW_ID that is `df.dtypes` `bigint`. The ROW_IDs look something like the table below, which doesn't seem to agree with the infered datatype.

| ROW_ID |
| --- |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJfsAAA |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJftAAA |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJfyAAB |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJfvAAB |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJfwAAB |
| AABBVMAGRAAAJf3AAI |

EDIT:

I tried casting the datatype from `bigint` to `string` using:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
correct_dtypes = df.withColumn('ROW_ID', col('ROW_ID').cast(StringType()))
correct_dtypes.write.jdbc('jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service', create_table,
                          mode='overwrite',
                          properties={'user': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using `createTableColumnTypes` option during saving  and cast the troublemaking bigint column to varchar2 on oracle dbs side:

```
(correct_dtypes.write.
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "ROW_ID VARCHAR2(18)")
.jdbc('jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service',
                          create_table, mode='overwrite',
                          properties={'user': 'user',
                          'password': 'password'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to solve that is the format of the ROWID column, which is not varchar, you must do it via this option for pyspark

```
df = sc.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option('driver', 'clase') \
    .option('url', 'url_jdbc') \
    .option('customSchema', 'ROWID VARCHAR(256), ORA_ROWSCN BIGINT')
```